# Sending hidden input to php script via ajax not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i am trying to get my ajax/json script to work, i have looked over stackoverflow, but can't find anything that looks like it would help. Basically all i am trying to do is when a user clicks on a submit button, for a hidden input value to be sent to another php script via ajax, where it will be changed etc... then sent back via ajax and displayed inside a div through a responce, i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

At the moment i am getting nothing, no output or anything.

I will try and be as thorough as possible in the code i give below, thanks for all the help.

AJAX script on main page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".add_detail_land_down").click(function () {
    var hidden_count = $('input[name=addon_detail_hidden_count]').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "ajax_script.php",
      data: {
        hidden_count: hidden_count
      },
      dataType: "json",
      statusCode: {
        success: function (data) {
          $("#total_hidden").html(data.total_hidden);
        }
      }
    });
  })
});
$(".add_detail_land_down").click();
</script>
```

The form head on main page (thought i might as well add it, just incase)

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

The hidden input on main page

```
<input type="hidden" name="addon_detail_hidden_count" id="addon_detail_hidden_count" class="addon_detail_hidden_count" value="1" />
```

The submit button for starting the ajax process on main page

```
<input name="add_detail_land_down" type="submit" class="add_detail_land_down" value="add_detail_down"/>
```

The code in ajax_script.php

```
    <?php 

$hidden_count = $_GET["hidden_count"];

$hidden_count = $hidden_count + 1;
include 'connect_to_mysql.php';

echo json_encode(array("total_hidden" => $hidden_count ));

 ?>
```

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: Have you used any developer tools, like Firebug, to watch the request / response cycle for errors?

Comment: Yes i have tried developer tools in chrome, and don't seem to be getting any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amongst all the other problems mentioned: `statusCode/success` syntax problem , and the click trigegr outlsde of `document.ready` you also need to prevent the browser default submittal of the form.

Currently your page is likely refreshing when you submit... normal browser behavior.

In the click handler you need to prevent this by either returning `false` or using `preventDefault()`

```
$(".add_detail_land_down").click(function (event) {

   /* use either of these */

   /* before your ajax code */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* or after your ajax code*/

     return false;

})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i think it actually solved it, here is the final code all together, a bit basic i know, but it is just to get it working, then i will move it to my main site, is there anything that could be approved?  Thanks so much for your help - http://pastebin.com/VSKyiwRy

Comment: only suggestion is that ID selectors are faster to find in browser, and usually easier to write instead of `name = ....`. Since your elements have ID's is not a big change. Another shorcut...you can chain the click trigger to the click handler function `$(selector).click(fuction(){ /* code*/}).click();`

Answer (score 3):

Why are you nesting your `success callback` inside **statusCode**

Supposed to be

```
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    $("#total_hidden").html(data.total_hidden);
}
```

**OR**

Use the status code **200** instead of **success**

```
dataType: "json",
statusCode: {
     200 : function (data) {
          $("#total_hidden").html(data.total_hidden);
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 this is probably the main reason for the failure - nice spot !

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i made the changes you suggested and along with some of the other answers here, it is now working

Comment: @AlWise .. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

statusCode is numeric and for your case should be `200` change it from `success` to `200` like so:

```
statusCode: {
    200: function (data) {
        $("#total_hidden").html(data.total_hidden);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your success callback should be specified like this (if you only care about 200):

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#total_hidden").html(data.total_hidden);
}
```

Also,  where you are trying to execute `click()` on the element might actually occur before the document is loaded and therefore execute before the onclick handler is ready. This should be within document ready after the onclick if you want to to fire automatically on document ready.

Comment: I think the first case should not be a problem.. The Key can be with or without Quotes .. that is not a problem.. Since it is normal javascript Object and not json string

Comment: @charlietfl At a minimum it is confusing as to your intent as you have a variable with that specific name specified.  Personally I would change the name of the variable. I have deleted from my answer though, as you are right that it is not actually an issue here.